# Linq to XML - Trying to select multiple nodes

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am working with XML that is close to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ROOT>
    <SECTION>
        <GROUP1>
            <NODE NAME="something" value="some value"/>
            <NODE NAME="something" VALUE="some value"/>
        </GROUP1>
        <GROUP2>
            <NODE NAME="something" value="some value"/>
            <NODE NAME="something" VALUE="some value"/>
        </GROUP2>
    </SECTION>
    <SECTION>
        <GROUP1>
            <NODE NAME="something" value="some value"/>
            <NODE NAME="something" VALUE="some value"/>
        </GROUP1>
        <GROUP2>
            <NODE NAME="something" value="some value"/>
            <NODE NAME="something" VALUE="some value"/>
        </GROUP2>
    </SECTION>
</ROOT>
```

I just want to select all the GROUP1 and GROUP2 elements together with a LINQ query. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I do need to be able to reference which group the node came out of later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
var groups = doc.Descendants("SECTION").Elements().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName.StartsWith("GROUP"));
Console.Write(groups.Count());
```

To find which group it comes from, we could get it by the parent of the XElement.

Answer (score 0):

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);

var group1 = doc.Descendants("GROUP1");
var group2 = doc.Descendants("GROUP2");
```

is that what you're after?

Comment: Close but I want to avoid the two queries because the data can be treated the same.